# Suppose that $A, B$ and $C$ are sets such that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$. Show that $A\subseteq C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose that $A, B$ and $C$ are sets such that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$. Show that $A\subseteq C$

My attempted try to solve the problem:

given that $A\subseteq B$, and $B\subseteq C$ then from the definition: 
$$ 
\forall x (x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B) \\
\forall x (x\in B\Rightarrow x\in C) 
$$
by Hypothetical Syllogism $ \forall x (x\in A\Rightarrow x\in C)$.

Hence  $A\subseteq C$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: And your question is....?  Okay, that is an absolutely correct proof but if ever anyone needed to be hit with the "explain it like I was 5" stick, it'd be this.  I've never heard of "Hypothetical Syllogism".

Comment: It is very well known, @fleablood.  That you are ignorant of this Syllogism, is your problem, not the asker's.  See [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism).  Now, how about apologizing to the asker for your comment due to your own ignorance.

Comment: ahmelq  Indeed.  Your proof is indeed correct.